# Conditional Formatting based on time is greater than in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, conditional-formatting

I want to add a conditional formatting rule.
When the time in column E is after 10:00:01 am to change color.
[image]

I used the rule if "Greater than" but when the cell returns time 03/25/2024 6:58:59 AM the rule applied is not working correctly.

[image]

I am sharing the Google Sheet sample file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhMP812BJRazPk9te_wTstoECCMW3TJpd7-8I7rkElI/edit?usp=sharing

To answer @rockinfreakshow
When I Try to add the formula "=mod(E14,1)> timevalue("08:30")" to my original file it says "Invalid Formula"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

***Apply to range***: `A4:A17`

Custom formula is:

```js
=mod(E4,1)> timevalue("10:00")
```

[image]

Comment: When I Try to add the formula "=mod(E14,1)> timevalue("08:30")" to my original file it says "Invalid Formula"

Comment: try with `=mod(E4;1)> timevalue("08:00")` this could be one of those cases of [comma v/s. semicolon convention](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)